# How to prevent null values from being entered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a simple foreach loop that is checking for each selected service (from a html form) and then saving that information into a database via Laravel 4 model. The information saves fine but it saves foreach input even if it's null. How can I JUST save the data if it's selected?

**Controller**

```
  public function getServices() {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);   

            $input = [
                    'rooms' => Input::get('rooms'),
                    'pr_deodorizer' => Input::get('pr_deodorizer'),
                    'pr_protectant' => Input::get('pr_protectant'),
                    'pr_sanitizer' => Input::get('pr_sanitizer'),
                    'fr_couch' => Input::get('fr_couch'),
                    'fr_chair' => Input::get('fr_chair'),
                    'pr_sectional' => Input::get('pr_sectional'),
                    'pr_ottoman' => Input::get('pr_ottoman'),
                    'pr_tile' => Input::get('pr_tile'),
                    'pr_hardwood' => Input::get('pr_hardwood')
            ];

            $empty = '<i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> No services were selected. Need help? Contact us';                          

            if(empty($input['rooms']) && empty($input['pr_deodorizer']) && 
                    empty($input['pr_sanitizer']) && empty($input['pr_protectant']) 
                    && empty($input['fr_couch']) && empty($input['fr_chair'])
                    && empty($input['pr_sectional']) && empty($input['pr_ottoman'])
                    && empty($input['pr_tile']) && empty($input['pr_hardwood'])
                     ){
                return Redirect::to('book/services')->withErrors($empty)->withInput();
            } 

            foreach($input as $services)
            {
                $service = new Service();

                $service->userID = $user->id;
                $service->services = $services;

                $service->save();
            }
            return Redirect::to('book/schedule');
    }
```

**This is how it's saving into my database:**

```
id  userID  services    price   created_at  updated_at
171 1          3    NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:24 2013-09-17 03:13:24
172 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:24 2013-09-17 03:13:24
173 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
174 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
175 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
176 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
177 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
178 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
179 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
180 1               NULL    2013-09-17 03:13:25 2013-09-17 03:13:25
```

The services column is what I am looking at. The user selected a service that had the serviceID of 3 but nothing else. But it's taking up empty rows which would cause errors in reporting. How can I get it to just save the data they actually fill? Is it possible with Laravel 4 validation?

Comment: It doesn't look very Laravel-ish... Think separation of concerns. Then check out the build-in validator helper to validate your data. You can enable mass assignment with `protected $guarded=[]`, then go from there, validate fields one by one in a service and inject that into the controller. If you follow best practices your controller shouldn't be longer than 5-10 lines.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. L4 doesn't have any type of validator to check any fields were inputted (that's why i just created a simple if(empty)). If I was to clean up the array's and the check against those arrays again then the controller would be dramatically smaller..this is still a development function. But that doesn't pertain to my question.

Comment: It's just an observation of your code, but my point is that you can abstract the logic that is repeated in that huge `if` statment into a service that uses the validator, then all you need is _one_ `isset`. Check on the docs for  "Extending The Validator Class" here http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Ok I will check that. I wasn't trying to be rude or anything. I am still learning and having to use hacky code to get results. Then I normally go back and clean up. I will check that page thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with elclanrs - the code doesnt look right.

But to answer your question - couldnt you just do this?

```
            foreach($input as $services)
            {
                $service = new Service();

                $service->userID = $user->id;
                $service->services = $services;

                if ( ! (is_null($services->services)))
                {
                    $service->save();
                }
            }
```

Comment: if you var_dump (%services->services) on the loop - what is shown? maybe you need to check for $services->services = ""  - because it is an empty string rather than null?

Comment: cannot var_dump $services->services because it doesnt exist. var_dumping $service->services only returns the one value "3"